# Unit ball weakly* compact

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, weak-convergence

So here is my problem,

I am trying to understand the proof of,

$X$ Banach space $\Rightarrow$ the unit ball in $X^*$ is weakly* compact.

The proof uses Tychonoffs Theorem to conclude the compacness. I think I undestand the whole proof except the following step,

Define $K_x:=[-||x||,||x||]\subset\mathbb R$ then we have,

$$\prod_{x\in X}K_x=\{f:X\rightarrow\mathbb R\;|\;|f(x)|\leq||x||\;\forall x \in X\}$$
and I really dont see why those sets are equal, can someone help me? 
Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An application
$$
f:X\to \Bbb R
$$can be considered as
$$
(f(x))_{x\in X} \in \Bbb R^X
$$

Comment: Thanks a lot, this makes sense.